# Why does this CSS styling stop jQuery UI sortable from firing the update event?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have recently updated a plugin that uses jQuery UI sortable and it stopped firing the `update` event.

I put together [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/haoh4L6d/1/) from my demo app page and after some trial and error found it is something in the CSS styling that causes the drag to always cancel.

The test code is very simple:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
    stop: function () {
        console.log("stop");
    },
    update: function () {
        console.log("update");
    }
});
```

Try and drag an item and it will always spring back as if cancelled. The stop event fires, but update will not fire as it never completes the drag.

Removing the last part of the CSS will allow it to work, but removing other parts will also cause it to fail, so it may be multiple styles causing the effect

```
.details {
    float: left;
}
```

What is it about the styling that causes this odd behaviour in `sortable`?

Comment: if .name and .details have float:left the .sortable li will have a height of 0, you need to give the li a height or some non floated content [http://jsfiddle.net/haoh4L6d/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/haoh4L6d/6/)

Comment: @Abraham Uribe: Please post as answer and I will accept. It is indeed the calculated LI height of 0 that causes it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if .name and .details have float:left

```
.name {
    float: left;
    color: blue;
}
.details {
    float: left;
}
```

the .sortable li will have a height of 0 and cause some bug in the _mouseDrag function in https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/sortable.js, you need to give the li a height

```
.sortable li {
    clear: both;
    height:20px;    //height of .name and .details
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/haoh4L6d/8/

or some non floated content like this

```
<li data-id="7"> 
    <div class="name">Test name 7</div>
    <div class="details">Details for item 7 (Display order: 1)</div>
    &nbsp;
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/haoh4L6d/6/

Answer (score 1):

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/haoh4L6d/4/)

the issue is because of the float left for `.display` it is not clearing so you can use `display:flex` or `display:inline-block` for li

```
ul.sortable li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display:flex;
}
```

but it will be better if you use default styles from jquery ui

Comment: `flex` is not a good option due to poor browser support and `inline-block` causes column issues, but +1 for the suggestions. The real issue is the 0-height of the LIs (which is a side-effect of the floated child divs). Have asked @Abraham Uribe to post his comment as answer.